# Not able to activate the site template in solutions gallery : SharePoint 2010

Tags: site-template, solution-package, solution-deployment

I have created a site from Decision  Meeting work-space template, made some modifications(added 2 Extra columns of date time datatype into Agenda list, added a new list for comments). I have saved this site as a site template.

Now I am not able to activate the site template in Solutions Gallery.

ULS log is showing these errors:

1. Solution Deployment : Missing one or more of the following attributes from the root node in solution BOD Meeting Template.wsp: assembly '', type ''.
2. Invalid SharePoint XSD: template\xml\wss.xsd (line 140 char 6)
3. System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: 'anyAttribute' must be the last child

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution

Open the file "wss.xsd" at below path
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML"

Find all xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"

in the file and verify that it is the last child if not move it to the last position . see below piece of code.

```
<xs:attribute name="PrependId" type="TRUEFALSE" />
<xs:attribute name="DisplaceOnUpgrade" type="TRUEFALSE" />
<xs:attribute name="UserSelectionMode" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="UserSelectionScope" type="xs:int" />
<xs:attribute name=”NoCrawl” type=”TRUEFALSE” />
<xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
```

In my case code was like -

```
<xs:attribute name="PrependId" type="TRUEFALSE" />
<xs:attribute name="DisplaceOnUpgrade" type="TRUEFALSE" />
<xs:attribute name="UserSelectionMode" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="UserSelectionScope" type="xs:int" />
<xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />    
<xs:attribute name=”NoCrawl” type=”TRUEFALSE” />
```

Changing the position of anyAttribute to the end resolved the issue :)